# Optimizing GitHub Pages: Streamlining File Transfer for Custom Domain Structure

Tags: github, subdomain, github-pages

On my website moonstruck.pro, which is hosted on GitHub Pages, the **initial page serves as a file explorer for my various projects**. Currently, when I wish to add a new website to the collection, **I manually copy the folders and files** from the specific repository to the GitHub Pages repository associated with my domain.

This manual process is necessary because I aim to maintain a structured URL hierarchy for easy navigation, with links formatted like:

**moonstruck.pro**
|
|-moonstruck.pro/website1
|-moonstruck.pro/website2

However, **I am exploring more efficient methods to streamline this process**. The goal is to **avoid the manual copying** of files into the GitHub Pages directory while still preserving the desired URL structure. **How would I do this?** Note, I use VScode

[My base website repo](https://github.com/MoonstruckSpirit/BaseWebsite)
[My Individual Website Repo (example)](https://github.com/MoonstruckSpirit/ohmyfood)
[My website itself](https://moonstruck.pro/)

*the website is up if you want to visit it for better ideas*